# Text conversion UTF-8 to latin1 issue

Tags: r, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I want to do some text analysis of instagram photo descriptions which often contain a mix of text, hashtags, @username, urls etc. and are also written in different languages. My method of extraction of the text seems to have stored the text in UTF-8.  My first task is to convert all the strings to latin1 before identifying languages and then translating.  I have a feeling its because the italian text contains an emoji code ðŸ˜, which the converter cant handle? Any help or directions to good tutorials appreciated!

```
t.de <- "mein bozen. schÃ¶nheit liegt im auge des betrachters. worauf 
richtest DU tagtÃ¤glich deinen blick? auf die vielen kleinen wunder des 
lebens\\, auf das lÃ¤cheln eines gesprÃ¤chspartners\\n#lavitaebella 
#perspektivenwechsel #entscheidedich #blickwinkel 
#schÃ¶nheitliegtimaugedesbetrachters"

t.it <- "ðŸ˜\u008dðŸ˜\u008dCi si puÃ² innamorare di una ricamatice??? 
ðŸ˜\u008dðŸ˜\u008d Personalizzazioni di tutti i tipi!! #ricamo #ricamato 
#personalizzato #elefante #palloncini #tenero #baby #nascita #amoredimamma 
#cuccioloso"

iconv(t.de, "UTF-8","latin1") #this works fine
iconv(t.it, "UTF-8","latin1") #this doesnt work

rawde=stri_encode(t.de, from="UTF-8", to="latin1", to_raw=TRUE)
stri_encode(rawde, "latin1")   #using the 'stringi' approach also works for de but not for it
```

Comment: Those strings aren't UTF8. `Ã¶` isn't a Unicode character, it's two characters in whatever codepage you used to save the script file. Most likely, Latin1. You *don't* need to convert anything anyway, R works with UTF8 just fine. If you get garbled text it's because you're trying to read or display UTF8 as if it were Latin1. You may have to change your terminal's or environment's codepage (through eg the LC_ALL enviropnment variable  in Linux). If you create any scripts that contain non-USASCII characters you should save them as UTF8.

Comment: What OS are you using? If you use Linux, what are the contents of LC_ALL ? How did you read the files?

Comment: Im using Windows 10 on a work networked PC, which probably doesnt easily allow tinkering with the settings.  I read the files using a json to csv online converter

Comment: On the contrary, Windows uses Unicode natively, since the Windows NT days.  How did you read the files? Why do you think you need to convert the text *at all*? Did you get garbled text in the console window? In that case you need to configure the console to display Unicode properly, not modify the text.

Comment: R and RStudio often display Unicode characters outside the US-ASCII range as `<U+...>`, not as `Ã¶`. This means that the text you posted was read as if it were ISO-8859-1 already, that's why you have this problem. Your reading code treated the two bytes as two separate characters instead of just one. Most file reading methods accept an `encoding` parameter which you should set to `utf-8`, eg `read.delim(file='filename',encoding='UTF-8')`

Comment: Yes thanks!  the encoding='UTF-8' worked.  The italian text displays correctly now and the emojis have been converted to U0001f.... code which makes their removal a lot easier.